# ping: unknown host

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, ping, hostname

Since few days, my dedicated server (Ubuntu 13.04) is no longer able to ping or connect to my NAS through DNS (hostname -> kr1.synology.me ) . The IP address ( 178.83.88.248 ) address against , is still reachable, I can ping to it, and also connect it via SSH.

Concretely I can do this :

```
sudo ssh root@178.83.88.248
sudo ping 178.83.88.248
```

But not this ( whereas before yes) :

```
sudo ssh root@example.com
sudo ping example.com
```

The problem is not from NAS side, because I can still reach it with root@kr1.synology.me from my local machine. The problem occurs only from my dedicated server.

Here are some options I did recently on my server:

- I installed *ufw* and configured it to only allow some ports
- I prevented the ability to connect as root in SSH
- I prevented the ability to connect with SSH password (key required)
- I installed and configured *denyhosts* and *fail2ban*
- I installed *rkhunter* and *chkrootkit*
- I added no recursion & "Not Disclosed" to *Bind9* configuration
- I added *nospoof* to `/etc/host.conf`

Will you help me solve the problem? I spent several hours on it and can not clearly identify the cause.

Comment: ensure ufw is allowing port 53 udp (DNS), then fiddle with the bind9 configuration you added. You seem to know what you're doing, so I suggest you try reverting your changes one by one and see which one caused this. My hunch is it's one of those two since it's clearly a DNS issue.

Comment: Add *spoofalert* to `/etc/host.conf` alerts are logged in `syslog`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to roadmr, I managed to solve the issue.

Indeed it was a problem related with bind9 configuration:

After I removed this two lines from the file "/etc/bind/named.conf.options", the issue was solved:

```
recursion no;
version "Not Disclosed";
```

I had added this two lines following an article which describe some tips to keep your server secured (point 6):

http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics